# Why did I lose rep due to "User was removed"?

Tags: support, reputation

I had a look at my "reputation" a few minutes ago and saw I "lost" 15 point due to:

```
-15     2 days ago
-15     09:41   removed     User was removed
```

I don't understand the reason for this. Can anyone explain? Is it something I did and shouldn't have / or something someone else did?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that was due to a user who had upvoted you deleting their account. Nothing you did wrong.  I also lost rep (`-270`) at the exact same time. When a user gets deleted, all of their voting and the reputation associated with it also goes away.

Don't worry about it. Go write an awesome answer or awesome question and you can get that rep back in just a few minutes.

Comment: Hea, thanks. Hmm, that seems kinda a strange way to handle something like a users reputation (I mean, if you put much credence in online reputation).

Surely if someone deletes their account, what ever points they awarded someone should stay? 

I guess it's to combat gaming the system?

TBH, I wasn't worried, just curious :) thanks.

Comment: That is correct. The user requested his account be deleted, and this is the result. When an account is deleted, their posts and data are converted to an anonymous account, in order to leave the thread of Q&A intact. Since an anonymous account can't upvote or downvote a post, all such rep gains are removed. It may not be a perfect system, but it's at least going to affect everyone equally, or as close to it as possible. It's also why deleting an account is discouraged.

Comment: Is there any way we can publicise this? I noticed the same and was confused too.

Comment: @Mac: I think having this question and answer on meta is enough... Only additional thing we could do is "feature" this meta-question so that it shows up in the Community Bulletin, but I think that's overkill for this.